# Granting access to Java Logger with java.policy file not working in Domino 9.0.1

Tags: security, java, ibm-domino

After I upgraded our 32bit dedicated Windows 2003 server from 9.0 to 9.0.1 this part in *java.policy* file stopped working:

```
permission java.util.logging.LoggingPermission "control";
```

which means I'm not able to use Java `Logger`. I get this:

```
HTTP JVM: java.security.AccessControlException: Access denied (java.util.logging.LoggingPermission control)
HTTP JVM:   at java.security.AccessController.throwACE(AccessController.java:100)
HTTP JVM:   at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:166)
HTTP JVM:   at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:544)
HTTP JVM:   at java.util.logging.LogManager.checkPermission(LogManager.java:317)
HTTP JVM:   at java.util.logging.LogManager.checkAccess(LogManager.java:311)
HTTP JVM:   at java.util.logging.Logger.addHandler(Logger.java:548)
```

I even tried copying the java.policy file from 64bit 9.0 virtual server where it works and restarted HTTP. Then I tested with a replica of an application that works on 9.0 server and it gave this error on 9.0.1 server.

The Java code is in *Code/Java* elements and it is called from an XPage.

How do I grant permissions to Java in Domino 9.0.1?

**Update:**

If I add this:

```
permission java.security.AllPermission;
```

then it works. So it *is* reading the java.policy file but granting access to logging does not work any more, at least not the same way it works in 9.0.1. Granting `AllPermission` is definitely not the solution I'm looking for.

Lars Migula seems to have the [same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19436564/modified-java-policy-ignored-since-installing-fixpack-5-on-domino-8-5-3) after a fixpack install in 8.5.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IBM support told me this:

> this issue matches a known issue described in [SPR# RGAU9CSBWA](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/entdocview.wss?uid=swg1LO77612)
>   linked with APAR LO77612 . This issue was first reported in 8.5.3 FP 5
>   and reproduced also in 9.0.1

I added the link which does not work currently, hopefully because of temporary problems at IBM site. I was able to see this much of it:

> LO77612: MODIFIED JAVA.POLICY IGNORED AFTER INSTALLING FIXPACK 5 ON
>   DOMINO 8.5.3
>
> Temporary fix
>
> `java.security.AllPermission; to the java.policy file.`

They will create a Customer Report for me also and hopefully this gets fixed soon.

Answer (score 1):

By the way
put your changes in the java.pol file not the java.policy file.
Just create a it in the same directory as the java.policy file. java.pol doesn't get replaced by upgrades / fixpacks...

Comment: Yes I know but that's not the issue here.